# angular deployd grunt workflow

Tags: angularjs, deployd

I am having a hard time integrating deployd into an already existing angular grunt workflow. 
Did somebody ever accomplish to do this easily.
Steps taken so far:

- added deployd and grunt-deployd to the proji
- adjusted the gruntfile in x many ways
- project has a public folder where the angularjs resides.
- and the rest is the usual dpd create stuff

now dpd -d gets me to the dashboard but it collides with the grunt modules of the existing project mainly grunt-concurrent and instantly crashes dpd

if I run the proji with grunt server it does load the dashboard on port 7777 but its blank so one can not do anything the dashboard usually offers.
It further does not proxy the api endpoints properly to port 9000 it fails with cannot get.
I have seen projects on git trying to do the same but almost all of them are broken.
https://github.com/taras/grunt-deployd/issues/1
Like this guy that switched away from deployd.
I think its a pity as deployd is such a great thing. My friend said as well if the integration would be easier in situations where you do not want to do stuff with dpd-client and the dashboard white instead of black much more people would love to use it!
I would like to post my gruntfile but wanted to see first if thats useful at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:
Deployd has been updated to be able to integrate Grunt, Gulp or other dev tools with Deployd.
The documentation page for this feature is available here:
http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/use-grunt-or-gulp.html

**tldr**: you just need to add a package.json with deployd in the `dependencies` and gulp/grunt in your `devDependencies`.

---

Old answer: Running deployd with Grunt, Gulp or any other Nodejs module is a [known](https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/172) [issue](https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/320).
I proposed a [pull request](https://github.com/deployd/deployd/pull/363) that fixes the problem, but more tests are needed to be accepted.

Temporarily, I use the [fork](https://github.com/NicolasRitouet/deployd) of the pull request and add this repo in my [package.json](https://github.com/NicolasRitouet/kinoa/blob/master/package.json) ([here's a working example](https://github.com/NicolasRitouet/kinoa)):
`"dependencies": {
    "deployd": "nicolasritouet/deployd"
}`